# Run next cloud build trigger after two other finished successfully

Tags: triggers, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

Let's say that currently my CI/CD pipeline runs these two triggers after merging. (`0` and `1`)

[image]

And in order to run `Trigger production deployment` I need both to finish successfully. Is there a way to run them (`Cypress E2E` and `Python E2E`) separately, and wait for each to "enable" the "1 of 2" and "2 of 2" required conditions to then execute the deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronizing Cloud Builds to trigger a 3rd one can be done but it's complex.

However, it exists an option on [Cloud Build to run steps in parallel](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order#examples). According to the documentation, you can do that

```
steps:
  - name: ...
    id: cypress
    args: ...
  - name: ...
    id: python
    args: ...
    waitFor: ['-']

  - name: ...
    id: deploy
    args: ...
    waitFor: ['cypress','python']
```

If you need more CPU to run all the steps in parallel, you can [configure the machine type](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/increase-vcpu-for-builds#increase_vcpu_for_default_pools)

Comment: Fair enough, this seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks for the suggestion.